# chrome developer tool before and after used inspector to HTML elements

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, phantomjs

I use phantomjs to test web page. When first time web loaded, I try to use chrome developer too in console tab, the selector can't get the element(see the picture line 1 & 2). At the same time the error show `TypeError: null is not an object`in command line.

Then I select the inspector to check the object, after this behavior, the same code in console suddenly can get the object(see the picture line 3 & 4)

[image]

Why it will happen？ How can I fix the `null` error?
HTML Code:

```
 <table class="menu" border="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td align="center"><a class="left_menu" href="javascript:QueryPool('USignInOut.aspx','簽到退')" style="WIDTH: 120px; HEIGHT: 27px" title="Sign In/Out">簽到退</a><a class="left_menu" href="javascript:QueryPool('OverTimeMain.aspx','加班')" style="WIDTH: 120px; HEIGHT: 27px" title="Overtime">加班</a><a class="left_menu" href="javascript:QueryPool('AbsentMain.aspx','請假')" style="WIDTH: 120px; HEIGHT: 27px" title="Taking Leave">請假</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is loaded after document load?

Comment: Yes, use `onLoadFinished()`

Comment: cannot get the connection between chrome developer tool and phantomjs